# Which event should i use, to get edit order action

Tags: edit-order

I need to trigger my logic only if somebody will edit order in magento admin panel. 
Event `sales_order_save_after` work also when my order is created normal way.
So this is not suitable to my task.

Is there any special event?  Or should i create some condition to check out if order was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to check it. In order is method $order->getOriginalIncrementId(), and if this method return false it mean that new order is created otherwise method return id of edited order.

Answer (score 4):

You should go for `sales_order_save_before`, then check if the model is new by calling:

`$model->isObjectNew();`

That will make sure the product is being saved, and it's not new.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I receive always true from  $model->isObjectNew(), (when i use sales_order_save_before) and always false when i use sales_order_save_after. So I can't decide if order was edited or created.